# opencv image stitching

Tags: opencv

I'm already looking for hours but I can't find the problem.

I get the following error when I want to stitch two images together:

```
OopenCV error: assertion failed (y==0 || data && dims >=1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned > size.p[0])) in unkown function...
```

This is the code (pano.jpg was already stitched together in a previous run of the algorithm were the same algorithm did work...):

```
cv::Mat img1 = imread("input2.jpg");
cv::Mat img2 = imread("pano.jpg");

std::vector<cv::Mat> vectest;
vectest.push_back(img2);
vectest.push_back(img1);
cv::Mat result;
cv::Stitcher stitcher = cv::Stitcher::createDefault( false );
stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.01);
detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher *matcher = new detail::BestOf2NearestMatcher(false, 0.001/*=match_conf*/);
detail::SurfFeaturesFinder *featureFinder = new detail::SurfFeaturesFinder(100);
stitcher.setFeaturesMatcher(matcher);
stitcher.setFeaturesFinder(featureFinder);
cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch( vectest, result );
```

You can find the images here:

- pano.jpg: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5276376/pano.jpg
- input2.jpg: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5276376/input2.jpg

**Edit**:
I compiled opencv 2.4.2 myself but still the same problem...

The system crashes in the stitcher.cpp file on the following line:

```
blender_->feed(img_warped_s, mask_warped, corners[img_idx]);
```

In this feed function it crashed at this line:

```
int y_ = y - y_tl;
            const Point3_<short>* src_row = src_pyr_laplace[i].ptr<Point3_<short> >(y_);
            Point3_<short>* dst_row = dst_pyr_laplace_[i].ptr<Point3_<short> >(y);
```

And finally this assertion in mat.hpp:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*y);
}
```

strange that everything works fine for some people here...

Comment: I am able to run your code with your images without getting the error. Are you sure there is no problem reading the image files?

Comment: No it crashes exactly on the last line. Is it possible that there are some bugs in some versions of opencv in the stitcher module? What version of openCV do you use?

Comment: I testet it with OpenCV 2.4.2.

Comment: This is a big hammer, but you could build opencv in debug mode and step through that `stitch` method to see exactly which condition is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I stitching images now,but not using stitch High Level Functionality instead encode every step by opencv2.4.2. As far as I know, you could have a try about first `SurfFeaturesFinder`, second `BestOf2NearestMatcher`. Just a try, Good luck!